# Overlap of icons without absolute in HTML5

Tags: css, html, font-awesome-4

I have the following snippet to render an icon overlapped with another. The whole div is a link. Currently I'm using position:absolute and adjusting the overlap. How can I do it without the absolute position. I also want the whole div on the right side of the screen (currently its on the left).

```css
.btn-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 25px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;l
}

.count {
  position: absolute;
  top:8px;
  left:38px;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">   
<div class="">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-inbox fa-2x"></i> 
        <span id="red-circle" class="btn btn-circle"></span>
        <span id="toDosCount" class="count">9</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: why don't you want to use absolute positioning?

Comment: I go with Starscream, even though hes a decepticon, no problem with `position: absolute` here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use absolute positioning alongside `float: right` if you make the containing div have `position: relative`

This makes the absolute positions of the inner spans relative to the div rather than the page.

A few tweaks to the top and right/left values and:

```css
.btn-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  right: -4px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;    
}

.count {
  position: absolute;
  top: -4px;
  right: -1px;
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:white;
  padding: 2px;
}

.wrapper {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">   
<div class="wrapper">
      <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-inbox fa-2x"></i> 
        <span id="red-circle" class="btn btn-circle"></span>
        <span id="toDosCount" class="count">9</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```

I also nudged the whole thing to the left a little so it wasn't obscured by the snippet FULL PAGE

Comment: Still the whole div is on the left side of the screen when I run this snippet

Answer (score 0):

Either you need to position it correctly or reduce the font size:

**Snippet**

```css
.btn-circle {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: 0;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

div a {position: relative;}

.count {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: 5px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">   
<div class="">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="fa fa-inbox fa-2x"></i> 
    <span id="red-circle" class="btn btn-circle"></span>
    <span id="toDosCount" class="count">9</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: You are still using absolute and the whole is still on left. I want it to be on the right. If I use float:right, it wouldn't work as the position is absolute.

Comment: When did I ask you to use float: right. Just right: 0 will work.

Comment: still the div is on the left side of the screen when I run this snippet

Comment: It works fine now. But I cannot change the size of the circle. It must be 30px X 30 px